# Show a failure if suite fails in BeforeSuite

Tags: java, testng

I have been running TestNG for quite some time successfully.  I have over 1000 suite XMLs all doing well except for one issue.  I have a `@BeforeSuite` which sets things up, gets stuff from a database, etc, etc.  If something causes a failure in `BeforeSuite()`, I want the suite to fail and skip the remaining tests.  It skips just fine, but the reporting shows things like...  `0 Pass, 0 Fail, 28 Skipped`.  I want it to show `0 Pass, 1 Fail, 27 Skipped`.  Due to it showing no failures post-processing is handling the suite incorrectly.  How can I get the first test to show as Fail if the `@BeforeSuite` fails?

BTW, I'm currently using things such as:

```
Assert.fail("OMS Database Query update failed for itemnumber= " + sPartnumber + ". Zero rows returned.");
```

in `BeforeSuite()`.

Comment: Why do you understand by `BeforeSuite` ? It's not a `@Test` so TestNg will not make it fail

Comment: @gregMa how are you doing the post-processing, like how are you planning to get the count of passed/failed tests? Note that testng displays another message like `Configuration Failures: 1`. This might be useful. Also please mention the version of testNG in the question